# Plotting histogram for same bin size but different values in each bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting histogram where **bin size is 10** each distributed from 1 to 100, now I have to plot
these values of *y= [1852, 1111, 1110, 1111, 741, 1482, 371, 370, 371, 1110]* for each bin.
Lets say for bin 0, I have 1825, bin1 I have 1111. on *x-axis* I have 1 to 100 while on y axis it goes to 10000. Tried the following code but not working.

```
y=[b0, b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9]
plt.hist(y, bins=10)
```

Comment: It seems you might want a [bar plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) instead?

Comment: i tried but it wasnt working

Comment: please share codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?)

```
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = range(10, 101, 10)
>>> plt.bar(x, y, width=9, tick_label=x)
<BarContainer object of 10 artists>
```

Output:

[image: Bar Plot]